# Regular expression must contain and may only contain

Tags: python, regex

I want a regular expression for python that matches a string which must contain 4 digits, it may not contain any special character other than "-" or ".", and it may only contain uppercase letters. I know the following matches text with 4 digits or more. How would I add the rest of the criteria?

`[0-9]{4,}`

An example would be:
**ART-4.5-11** is good, **ART5411** is good, **76543** is good, but **aRT-4!5-11** is bad since it contains a lowercase char and a special char that is not "-" or "."

Comment: Also, [`^(?=(?:[^0-9]*[0-9]){4})[0-9A-Z.-]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/bhgDL0/1/).

Comment: This works as well. Thank you! I am still struggling to understand lookahead assertions and when to use them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pattern:

```
pattern = '^[A-Z.-]*(\d[A-Z.-]*){4,}$'
```

- `^` - start of the word
- `[A-Z.-]*` - any number of optional non-digit "good characters": letters, periods or dashes
- `(\d[A-Z.-]*){4,}` - 4 or more groups of a digit and other "good characters"; this part provides at least 4 digits
- `$` - end of the word

Examples:

```
re.match(pattern, "ART-4.5-11")
# <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='ART-4.5-11'>    
re.match(pattern, "ART5411")
# <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='ART5411'>
re.match(pattern, "aRT-4!5-11") # No match
re.match(pattern, "76543")
# <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 5), match='76543'>
```

Comment: Nice regex! May I suggest adding a description of the pattern for the benefit of the OP and other readers?

Comment: @KenY-N Sure. Added.

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you for the explanation as well!